# What is the right way to check the Null String in Database in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to restriction on database when in database no data in row than can't show the exception I am simply want to restriction on Null value

```
  if ([[Utility checkNullValues:tInfo.product_price]isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [Utility showAlertView:@"Sorry" message:@"No Product You Buy." viewcontroller:self];
      }
```

And that is the error:

> 2015-06-03 12:35:38.320 NiColi[28363:2438247] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***
>   +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Comment: How can you compare null value with empty string.
both are different.

Comment: How do you retrieve `tInfo`? Is `product_price` a _simple_ property or is there a dedicated getter in place?

Comment: tInfo_productPrice fetch the record from the database now i want when in database no data in the row than can't occur the exception only show this no data thats it

Comment: NSString *strQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT SUM(CAST(product_price as decimal)) AS TOTAL FROM cart_user where user_id =%@",[Utility getUserId]];
    ReturnStatement = [obj getStatement:strQuery];
    
    while(sqlite3_step(ReturnStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    FetchRecordDatabase *tInfo = [[FetchRecordDatabase alloc]init];
        tInfo.product_price = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(ReturnStatement, 0)];

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str = ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)] : nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this macro:

```
#define NULL_VALIDATION(obj) ({ __typeof__ (obj) __obj = (obj); __obj == [NSNull null] ? nil : obj; })
```

This macro will return `nil` if the passed object is `NULL` or else, the object itself. Usage:

```
if ([NULL_VALIDATION(tInfo.product_price) length] == 0) { 
   [Utility showAlertView:@"Sorry" message:@"No Product You Buy." viewcontroller:self];
}
```

**P.S:** Don't forget to import `<objc/runtime.h>`

Comment: still crash the program and when NULL_Validation function than generate the warning the warning is this    "Comparison of distinct  pointer type(typeof(tInfo_productprice) (aka NSString ) as NULL"

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
+ (id)validateNullFields:(id)value{

    if (value != NULL && ![value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        return  value;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give very best and better solution for you question.Even if you pass anything to this,it gives you the good answer.So you can simply use this method.

```
#pragma mark - check string is empty or not
- (void)checkEmpty:(NSString *)check
{
    @try 
    {
      if (check.length==0)
        check = @" ";
      if([check isEqual:[NSNull null]])
        check = @" ";
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) 
    {
      check = @" ";
    }
}
```

Just call this method(with string(parameter)) where you want to send the data to database.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79525/discussion-on-answer-by-user3182143-what-is-the-right-way-to-check-the-null-stri).

Answer (score -1):

I hope this may helps you...

```
-(BOOL)isNullString:(NSString *)dbString{

    if ([dbString isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        return YES;
    }
    else if (dbString == nil){
        return YES;
    }
    else if ([dbString isEqualToString:@""]){
        return YES;
    }
    else if ([dbString isEqualToString:@"null"]){
        return YES;
    }
    else if ([dbString isEqualToString:@"(null)"]){
        return YES;
    }
    else if ([dbString caseInsensitiveCompare:@"NULL"] == NSOrderedSame){
        return YES;
    }
    else if (dbString == 0){
        return YES;
    }
    else{
        return NO;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

It returns **YES** for empty and **NO** for somevalues.

Comment: still crash the Program Jaleel

Comment: Your method signature is `(NSString *)dbString`, so testing for `isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]` is nonsense. You should only use `isKindOfClass:` on an `id` object (assumed to be NSObject*) or for testing subclasses.